# Fastlane changelog_from_git_commits export to file

Tags: fastlane

Hi guys have a small issue with fastlane change log. So I want to add the result of the `lane_context[SharedValues::FL_CHANGELOG]` to a file, Because passing a long string that have some times unexpected characters could lead to a failure.

i have tried echo, printf , but no success.

eg if i have

```
changeLog = "JIRA-Ticket, some text,
fixed pop-up crash
JIRA-1, JIRA-22
fixed empty SendingMethod screen
some string with ", and other chars
added UILabel+Utils, title case."
```

and i try
`echo $changeLog > "my_doc.txt"` it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yah just added ruby write comand and it works fine

```
File.open("../change_log.txt", 'w') { |file| file.write(changeLog) }
```